# In Keras, how to get the layer name associated with a "Model" object contained in my model?

Tags: keras, keras-layer, conv-neural-network

I built a Sequential model with the VGG16 network at the initial base, for example:

```python
from keras.applications import VGG16
conv_base = VGG16(weights='imagenet',
                  # do not include the top, fully-connected Dense layers 
                  include_top=False,
                  input_shape=(150, 150, 3))

from keras import models
from keras import layers

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(conv_base)
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'))
# the 3 corresponds to the three output classes
model.add(layers.Dense(3, activation='sigmoid'))
```

My model looks like this:

```python
model.summary()
```

> ---
>
> ```python
> Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
> =================================================================
> vgg16 (Model)                (None, 4, 4, 512)         14714688  
> _________________________________________________________________
> flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 8192)              0         
> _________________________________________________________________
> dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 256)               2097408   
> _________________________________________________________________
> dense_8 (Dense)              (None, 3)                 771       
> =================================================================
> Total params: 16,812,867
> Trainable params: 16,812,867
> Non-trainable params: 0
> _________________________________________________________________
> ```

Now, I want to get the layer names associated with the vgg16 Model portion of my network.  I.e. something like:

```python
layer_name = 'block3_conv1'
filter_index = 0

layer_output = model.get_layer(layer_name).output
loss = K.mean(layer_output[:, :, :, filter_index])
```

However, since the vgg16 convolutional is shown as a Model and it's layers are not being exposed, I get the error:

> ValueError: No such layer: block3_conv1

How do I do this?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The key is to first do `.get_layer` on the Model object, then do another `.get_layer` on that specifying the specific vgg16 layer, THEN do .output:

`layer_output = model.get_layer('vgg16').get_layer('block3_conv1').output`

Comment: You can use the layer's summary: `model.get_layer('vgg16').summary()`

Answer (score 32):

To get the name of the layer from the VGG16 instance use the following code.

```
for layer in conv_base.layers:
    print(layer.name)
```

the name should be the same inside your model. to show this you could do the following.

```
print([layer.name for layer in model.get_layer('vgg16').layers])
```

like Ryan showed us. to call the vgg16 layer you must call it from the model first using the get_layer method.

Answer (score 16):

One can simply store the name of layers in the list for further usage

```
layer_names=[layer.name for layer in base_model.layers]
```

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me :)

```
for idx in range(len(model.layers)):
  print(model.get_layer(index = idx).name)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the layer's summary:

```
model.get_layer('vgg16').summary()
```